# Cross Table Dependency/Constraint in SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, constraints, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Take the example that I have of a table called `classes` that holds  university classes and a table called `students` that holds students. A class has many students and a student can only take one class. (1 to many relationship). If I had a column in `classes` that stored the total number of students a class has, this feels like it should violate 3NF. But the dependency is in a separate table. What is this dependency called? And can we say this is violating 3NF? Because in some sense it has all the problems of a 3NF violation. I was wondering if this was a related case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> But the dependency is in a separate table.

You mean there is a dependency (in the everyday sense) *on* another table. We say there is a *constraint on* the two tables. (They depend on each other.) In addition to the FK (foreign key) constraint that every `students` `classes` value is a `classes` `class` value.

> What is this dependency called?

We can reasonably categorize the constraint as "inter-table". It is that `classes` equals `SELECT class, SUM(student) AS total FROM classes LEFT JOIN students USING (class) GROUP BY class`.

> And can we say this is violating 3NF?

The constraint doesn't involve violating a NF. Moreover normalization applies only to a single table and its FDs (functional dependencies).

(A straightforward design is to have base `students`, base `classes1` that is the original `classes` without `total`, and `VIEW classes AS SELECT class, SUM(student) AS total FROM classes1 LEFT JOIN students USING (class) GROUP BY class`.)

---

> If I had a column in `classes` that stored the total number of students a class has, this feels like it should violate 3NF.

Whether a table is in a given NF (normal form) has nothing to do with any other tables. (We say a database is in a given NF when all its tables are.) Whether your design is nevertheless bad is [another matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40697773/3404097).

Since a class has just one total number of students, there is a FD (functional dependency) of `total` on `class` in `classes`, ie `class` functionally determines `total`.

[We say that a set of columns functionally determines another set in a table when each subrow for the first always appears with the same subrow for the second.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27504915/3404097) Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by projections of it that join back ot it, per the FDs & JDs (join dependencies) that hold in it. [There is redundancy in a database when two tables say the same thing about the business/application situation; but not all redundancy is bad.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27809411/3404097) Learn proper information modeling & database design.

It may or may not violate a NF to have your class student count as a column in `classes`. What FDs violate a NF depends on all the FDs present and the NF. (And it only make sense to talk about a particular FD in a particular table violating a particular NF if you are talking about a particular part of a particular definition of that NF.)

(If a DBMS-calculated/computed/generated column violates a NF that would hold without it then that is not a problem, *because* it is controlled by the DBMS. You can think of the table as view of the table without the column.)

> But the dependency is in a separate table.

When a sequence of database states cannot hold all the values possible per the the columns of tables we say *constraints* hold or the database is *constrained*. FDs (functional dependencies), MVDs (multi-valued dependencies), JDs (join dependencies), INDs (inclusion dependencies), EQDs (equality dependencies) and other "dependencies" (which technically are *expressions* given a context) are each associated with certain constraints. CKs (candidate keys), PKs (primary keys), superkeys (SQL `PK` & `UNIQUE NOT NULL`), FKs (foreign keys) (which technically are all *column sets*) & other notions are also each associated with certain constraints. But arbitrary conditions can hold on a sequence of database states.

SQL has a distinct but related notion of a `constraint` characterized by a name and an expression/condition (constraint in the above sense), declared by appropriate syntax. A state is constrained by column typing, `PK`, `UNIQUE`, `NOT NULL` & `CHECK` constraints. `ASSERTION` gives an arbitrary condition on a state but it is not supported by most DBMSs. `CASCADES` supports some inter-state inter-table constraints. SQL `TRIGGER`s enforce arbitrary constraints. Indexes also enforce constraints in a DBMS-specific way.

---

> Because in some sense it has all the problems of a 3NF violation.

Your edits improved your question. Using the wrong words or using words in the wrong way at best states something that is not what we mean. But when what we write doesn't make sense it suggests that our problem, whatever else it involves, involves not knowing what the words mean. Forcing ourselves to use words correctly allows others to know what we really mean. Eg here maybe "... in the join of tables ... there would be a 3NF-violating FD ...". Even by explicitly saying that we are unsure we can communicate some of our vague groping without saying something that we don't mean. Eg your "this feels like ...". But it also leads us to clearly organize what we are faced with. This helps not only the problem we are working on but improves our problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

It does not violate normalization, but it would be painful to maintain rather than doing a count in your query.

Note: Junction tables are for many-to-many.

Comment: I am assuming that a student can only take one class.

Comment: Also,  `total students` is a calculated field. This violates 3NF.

Comment: @SepehrSobhani If it violates 3NF, can you point out which 1NF rule or partial or transitive functional dependency it violates?

Comment: Hugo, all relationships were originally represented by "junction tables" in Chen's method. One-to-one and one-to-many binary relationship relations can be denormalized into the entity relation for the determining entity set(s) in the relationship, but not when a composite key is required (i.e. many-to-many binary relationships and most higher arity relationships). That doesn't mean junction tables are invalid for one-to-one and one-to-many relationships, but they're usually not strictly required in those cases.