# Does the relational schema with some "aggregation" attributes satisfy Boyce–Codd normal form (BCNF)?

Tags: database-design, bcnf

Suppose a relational database has `employee` and `company` entity with `workFor` relation, such as

`employee`(**ssn**, first_name, last_name), where **ssn** is the key.

`company`(**company_name**, location), where **company_name** is the key.

`workFor`(**ssn**, **company_name**), where **ssn** and **company_name** are foreign keys.

Suppose the database is huge, and we need to query the number of employees for a company very often. Rather than request a query each time, we decide to add a attribute of `number_of_employ` somewhere in the relational schema for performance consideration. My question is that if we add the `number_of_employee` to the `company(company_name, location, number_of_employee)` relation, does it still satisfy the Boyce–Codd normal form (BCNF)? And is it a good design?

Intuitively, I do not think it still satisfies the BCNF because the `company_name` alone can not determine this attributes (and it is not a key any more). Is there any term for this "aggregation" attribute of `number_of_employ`, which is determined not by a specific value but by the whole `workFor` relation? What would be a good schema design for it if I have to add this attribute somewhere in my schema?

Comment: Why company_name is not an attribute of employee? Does an employee work for multiple companies?

Comment: I neglect this when I asked this question. We could assume an employee is allowed to work for more than one company. Where should I add the number_of_employee attribute? Add it to company relation? Or make a new relation with companyCount(company_name, number_of_employee)?

Comment: Add it to company, then add triggers to maintain  it consistent with the data.

Comment: What it stopping you from just applying the definition of BCNF? Asking us is asking us to rewrite your textbook & do your homework. And what does "good design" mean? Again, if you are asking us then you are asking us to write a textbook & apply it. PS "company_name alone can not determine this attribute" does not use "determine" in the sense it is meant in normalization, because in that table it *does* functionally determine. So again, you need to read & apply your textbook, & ask a question when you are stuck.

Comment: 1. The term for such an "aggregation" is... an aggregation (or aggregate (value)). 2. Do not think in terms of attributes, think in terms of business/application relation(ship)s/associations (on attributes) of interest to you, which is what relations/tables represent in the Relational Model (and the Entity-Relationship Model). (Once you have those plus what situtations can arise you know what states can arise & hence the constraints.) PS Please do not clarify in comments, edit your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a counter in a database Many-to-Many field to reduce lookups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407402/can-i-use-a-counter-in-a-database-many-to-many-field-to-reduce-lookups)