# What SQL query to access data from a table twice-removed, fully normalized

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

Let's say there are three tables, users, orders, transactions, which look like this:

```
Users: 
id | name
---------
1  | Mike
2  | Sara

Orders: 
id | user_id | total | transaction_id
-------------------------------------
1  |       1 |   100 |              1
2  |       2 |    10 |              2
3  |       1 |     5 |              1
4  |       1 |     4 |              3
5  |       1 |    40 |              3
6  |       2 |    80 |              2

Transactions: 
id | total |  created_at 
------------------------
1  |   105 | [timestamp]
2  |    90 | [timestamp]
3  |    44 | [timestamp]
```

And let's say I want to select users.name but sort the names representing the most recent activity (i.e. by most recent transaction).

As you can see the data I want is twice-removed (maybe misusing that word) in the sense that I would need to go through the orders table to figure out the most recent transaction.

I figured I would design it to be as normalized as possible but then I realized I had no idea how to structure a proper query for this and other similar scenarios. I can obviously pull all the data and sort it out in the application code. I could also of course add a "last_transaction_at" column on users that I keep in sync.

So I guess there's two pieces to the question. First is how to do this with a SQL query, and second is whether this is more or less efficient than de-normalizing.

Comment: If two users have the same name, what exactly do you want? Names listed in order of the most recent transaction of some user with that name? Or a list where the nth element is the name of the user with the nth most recent transaction time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select u.Name, MAX(created_at) TransactionTime FROM #Users u
INNER JOIN  #ORDERS o
ON u.Id = o.user_id
INNER JOIN #Transactions t
ON o.transaction_id = t.id
GROUP BY u.Name
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) desc
```

I feel the schema which you created in fine

Answer (score 0):

Normalization to higher normal forms replaces a table by components (tables that are projections of it) that (relational natural) join back to the original.

To make sense of `join`ing back in SQL, let's assume that when we normalized we treated `null` as just another value, except that columns shared by components were `not null`; that there are no duplicate rows; and that we ignore column ordering.

Then we get back the table via `select distinct * from` a sequence of `natural join`s of the components. Or via `select distinct` of each component *column name* `from` a sequence of `inner join`s of components `on` equality of same-named columns.

That ties normalization to `join`s. But you might not want to get back exactly a table that you decomposed into components. Why *do* we `join`? Each base table holds the rows that make a true *proposition* (statement) from some *predicate* (statement template) parameterized by column names:

```
-- user I is named N
User(I,N)
-- order I is user U spending $T in transaction X
Orders(I, U, T, X)
-- transaction I for $T was created on C
Transactions(I,T,C)
```

In a `from` an alias names a table like a preceding table but with each `column` renamed to `alias.column`. Its rows satisfy the predicate of the preceding table. `where` ANDs in its condition.

```
from Users u
--     user u.I is named u.N
where N = 'disantlor'
-- AND N = 'disantlor'
```

Then `a cross join b` holds the rows that satisfy the AND of alias predicates. And `a inner join b` holds the rows that satisfy the AND of alias predicates & the `on` condition.

```
from Users u
--     user u.I is named u.N
cross join Orders o
-- AND order o.I is user o.U spending $o.T in transaction o.X
inner join Transactions x on o.X = x.I
-- AND transaction x.I for $x.T was created on x.C AND  o.X = x.I
where o.U = u.I
-- AND o.U = u.I
```

So we `join` to get rows satisfying the conjunction of given predicates. And normalization replaces a table with predicates using ANDs by components with predicates that are conjuncts. [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Your design is subject to the constraint that `select id, total from Transactions` =

```
select transaction_id as id, sum(total) as total
from Orders
group by transaction_id
```

It's possible that you got this design from normalizing a certain original table without preserving FDs (functional dependencies), but probably what you mean by "normalized" is just "well-designed". [Cross Table Dependency/Constraint in SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45189447/3404097)